# Scroll bar in a Datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have spun my wheels on this for long enough.  I am trying to get a scrollbar to appear in a datagrid so the user will be able to look at all records in the datagrid. It is important that my Add Edit Delete buttons stay where the user can select them without scrolling the whole window.
Here is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFFAB.png)

```
            <TabItem Header="Revit Links" Width="100">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="58*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="78*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="733*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Label Content="Revit Links:" Height="Auto" Margin="10,35,10,0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <DataGrid x:Name="dgRevitLinks2" ItemsSource="{Binding RevitLinkedFiles}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelRevitLinkedFile}"
                                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                      CellStyle="{StaticResource CenteredDataGridCell}"
                                      Background="White" RowHeaderWidth="0" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC">


                                <DataGrid.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="dgRevitLinks_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.Resources>
                                <DataGrid.Columns>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Link Name" Binding="{Binding Path=RevitLinkType.Name}">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=OriginalFilePath}" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="New Path" Binding="{Binding Path=NewFilePath}" Width="*">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Option Rule" Binding="{Binding Path=Rules}" Width="Auto">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>

                                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding AddRevitLinkCommand}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditRevitLinkCommand}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteRevitLinkCommand}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Save" Command="{Binding SaveRevitLinkCommand}"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                            </DataGrid>
                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">

                                <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddRevitLinkCommand}" ToolTip ="Adds a Revit Linked File Option"/>
                                <Button Content="Edit" Command="{Binding EditRevitLinkCommand}" ToolTip ="Edits a Revit Linked File Option"/>
                                <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteRevitLinkCommand}" ToolTip ="Deletes a Revit Linked File Option"/>
                                <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveRevitLinkCommand}" ToolTip ="Saves changes to active project"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,16,10,7"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="26" ToolTip="A minimum of 1 Sheet Set Required of Lot Job Exports.">
                                <Run>RVT files must be replaced with .RVT Files</Run>
                            </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            </TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid row, which contains scrollable element, should not have Height="Auto" - it will grow indefinitely. Set Height="*" for it - it will be restricted by available height.

```
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
```

also DataGrid doesn't require additional ScrollViewer on outside - ScrollViewer is already included in DataGrid's template